# Serialize MultiPoint to GeoJSON file

Tags: c#, .net, geojson

using the GeoJson.Net lib, how do I serialize a `GeoJson.Net.Geometry.MultiPoint` to a VALID MultiPoint GeoJSON file?

All I can find is how to serialize a random Geometry object to a JSON file that cannot be read for instance in QGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the [tests for multi point](https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net/blob/master/src/GeoJSON.Net.Tests/Geometry/MultiPointTests.cs) there is a test that serializes a multipoint

```
var points = new List<Point>
{
    new Point(new Position(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906)),
    new Point(new Position(52.3711451105601, 4.895267486572266)),
    new Point(new Position(52.36931095278263, 4.892091751098633)),
    new Point(new Position(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906))
};

var multiPoint = new MultiPoint(points);

var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(multiPoint);
```

Let me know if there is anything you don't understand.